# How to Create a Batch File that Deletes only the first line in all .txt files in a specific folder and keeps the blank space

Tags: batch-file

Text in every file before running batch file:

> ```
> sometext1
> sometext2
> sometext3
> sometext4
> ```

Text in every file after running batch file:

> ```
>                 <-- (vacant line where sometext1 used to be)
> sometext2
> sometext3
> sometext4
> ```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What about using the [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) (given that the original text files do not contain any empty lines which got lost)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

A for /f would need precautions to process empty lines.
The following batch uses the simple for to iterate all (renamed) files.

```
@Echo off
CD /D "X:\path\to\your\folder"
Ren "*.txt" "*.txt.bak"
For %%A in (*.txt.bak) Do (
   >"%%~dpnA" Echo:
  >>"%%~dpnA" More +1 "%%A"
)
```

More +1 skips the first line when appending the rest of the file.
The modifier "%%~nA" removes the additional extension .bak from the name restoring the old file name.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options:

#### `findstr`

Supposing the last line of each text file is properly terminated by a line-break, you could use this code:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

for %%F in (".\*.txt") do (
    < "%%~F" (
        set /P =""
        echo/
        findstr "^"
    ) > "%%~F.tmp"
    move /Y "%%~F.tmp" "%%~F" > nul
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Disadvantage: if the last line is not terminated by a line-break, the used `findstr` command hangs; the first line is limited to a length of 1023 characters (including the line-break), the remaining lines are limited to 8192 characters (with line-break).

---

#### `more`

[LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411) already showed how to use this in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41348732), so this one is quite similar:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

for %%F in (".\*.txt") do (
    > "%%~F.tmp" echo/
    >>"%%~F.tmp" more +1 "%%~F"
    move /Y "%%~F.tmp" "%%~F" > nul
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Disadvantages: <kbd>TAB</kbd> characters are converted to <kbd>SPACE</kbd> characters; in case an input file contains more than 65534 lines, user interaction (pressing <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to process the next 65534 lines) is required; all lines are limited to a length of 65535 characters (excluding the line-break).

---

#### `for /F`

The nested `findstr` command is there to precede every line by a line number temporarily for them never to appear empty to `for /F` which ignores such; the prefix is later removed:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

for %%F in (".\*.txt") do (
    > "%%~F.tmp" (
        echo/
        for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "%%~F"') do (
            set "LINE=%%L"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            echo(!LINE:*:=!
            endlocal
        )
    )
    move /Y "%%~F.tmp" "%%~F" > nul
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Disadvantage: this is certainly the slowest approach; all lines are limited to a length of 8182 characters (excluding the line-break).

Comment: I think there has been a mistake. I said text IN a .txt not the name of the .txt file.

Comment: Thank-you For your help with This, the code I was originally using failed me. Interestingly enough, I was able to successfully accomplish this task with LotPings answer

Comment: All these approaches handle the text in the files as wanted, so I don't understand what's wrong...